# How to have an individual texture for different Displace modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I don't know if this is something Blender has, or if it is a bug. But I was trying to create a procedural rock using two different Displace modifiers each using it's own texture. However, every time I go to the Texture tab, and I change between them, it always changes that texture on each modifier to the one I'm using.

Example:

Displace 1 - Texture 1

Displace 2 - Texture 2

In the texture tab, it has Texture 1 selected, if I change to Texture 2 then this happens:

Displace 1 - Texture 2

Displace 2 - Texture 2

This makes it very hard to work with the Displace modifier.

Here is the blend file showing what I mean:

[image]

Comment: To avoid accidentally editing the wrong texture, you can always use [this little button](https://imgur.com/a/OKZe9eL) in the modifier to jump to the right one.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have done something wrong.

For the moment both the 2 modifiers have the same texture (called *Small*). So, for example, for the second *Displace* modifier, click on the *New Texture* button, it will create a *Small.001* texture (you could do the same directly into the *Material* panel actually):

[image]

Go into the *Material* panel, make sure that *Small > Small.001* are selected (you may have not selected the right modifier or texture here), choose the type of texture you want for this one:

[image]

Back into the modifiers, it seems to work, both the 2 modifiers have kept their texture:

[image]

Comment: But if you change the texture in the texture tab, it will change the textures on the modifiers.

Comment: if you are in the Texture panel, make sure that you have selected the good modifier on the top dropdown menu, then select the texture or create a new one, and choose its type

Comment: if it's still not good please show a video with your problem

Comment: I solved it by clicking the little button on the side as Robin Betts suggested. That seems to keep the right texture selected. Otherwise I kept getting the issue.

Comment: mmh that's weird, either you have a bug or you don't select the right modifier on the top of the Texture panel

Comment: Yea, it's really weird. Either way I'm marking this as solved. There are two solutions here for anyone else that gets this issue.